Are the 28 bitangents on quartic curves bounded distance away from each other?
We know that the 28 bitangents on a smooth plane quartic curve over $\mathbb{C}$ are all distinct. Are the bitangents bounded distance away from each other? More precisely, is there a constant $d>0$ such that for any smooth plane quartic curve $C$, the distance between any two distinct bitangent lines on $C$ are at least $d$? Here we measure the distance between two lines in $P^2$ using the Fubini-Study metric on $(P^2)^\vee\cong P^2$.
I am also interested in an answer for a similar question about the 27 lines on cubic surfaces: Is there a constant $d'>0$ such that for any smooth cubic surface $S$, the distance between any two distinct lines on $S$ are at least $d'$? Here we measure the distance between two lines in $P^3$ using the natural $U(4)$-invariant metric on the Grassmannian $G(2,4)\cong U(4)/(U(2)\times U(2))$.
Any insight or reference will be much appreciated. Thank you.

If you degenerate your quartic curve into a singular curve then some of the bitangents have the same limit; therefore the distance between them is not universally bounded. Similarly, if you degenerate a cubic surface some lines on it have the same limit, and therefore the distance between them is not universally bounded.

@Sasha: that seems to be a complete answer.

@LazzaroCampeotti: Almost --- a complete answer would also include an explanation why such degenerations do exist.

@Sasha: Got it. Thank you so much!
